# Serving `index.html` on Artifactory instead of rendering the directory index

Tags: artifactory

I've got some resources stored on an Artifactory server, along with some documentation. However, when I visit `/path/to/release/`, it renders a directory index instead of my `index.html`. Is there a setting I could use to render the webpage instead of the list of files?

Answer (score 2):

There is an Artifactory setting that will allow to browse the html files in the directory: "Allow content browsing", see:
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Advanced+Settings

However, the index.html will not be loaded automatically.

Comment: Any idea why the index.html does not load on the browser automatically?

Answer (score 0):

For serving automatically index.html, If you use Nginx as reverse proxy, you can set Nginx config, for example:

```
location ~ ^/artifactory/.*-docs-.*/.*$
{
    rewrite ^(.*)/$ $1/index.html break;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8081;
}
```